# Use JPQL to JOIN ON criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, jpql

I am using JPA to return a results set however want to exclude instructions (which are joined to groups and then forms) where deleted = true.

I would use the ON clause in the named query but it causes a hibernate exception because it isn't supported in version we are running (upgrading it is not currently an option). Also the version of JPA will not allow this to be done via the criteria builder either.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Form.findAllForms", query="SELECT DISTINCT f FROM Form f LEFT OUTER JOIN f.instructionGroups g LEFT OUTER JOIN g.instructions i")
// .. ON i.deleted = false
public class Form implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_id", nullable = false)
    @OrderColumn(name = "sortOrder")
    private List<InstructionGroup> instructionGroups = new ArrayList<>();



public class InstructionGroup implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructionGroup_id", nullable = false)
    @OrderColumn(name = "sortOrder")
    private List<Instruction> instructions =  new ArrayList<>();



public class Instruction implements Serializable {

    private boolean deleted;
```

Using the WHERE clause doesn't work either as it no longer returns the forms with deleted instructions attached where as I need to apply my condition at the join phase. Is my best option to write the native SQL and use that or can I stick with JPA to achieve this?

Comment: It looks as though what you want is a soft delete mechanism so, while this does not directly answer your question, you might find the [the following link](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-soft-delete-with-hibernate/) useful

Answer (score 0):

Use "WITH" clause in query to specify condition on join . Refer below query

query="SELECT DISTINCT f FROM Form f LEFT OUTER JOIN f.instructionGroups g LEFT OUTER JOIN g.instructions i WITH i.deleted=0